# How to fetch Index of row in pandas when certain condition has been met?

Tags: python, pandas

I am dealing with OHLC data of a stock in pandas. I have set 'date' column as index.

`max_high = df['2021']['high'].max()`
shall find the highest value in 'high' column for the year 2021.

I intend to find the index of that row in which such high exists, so that I can find minimum  value of low between a given date to date of such high by using something like:

`min_low=df['2020-01-02':'2021-01-03]['low'].min()`

I'm a beginner in  pandas, any suggestions would be welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For find index you can use `idxmax` and `idxmin`:

```
>>> max_high = df['2021']['high'].idxmax() 

>>> min_low = df['2020-01-02':'2021-01-03']['low'].idxmin()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `idxmax`:

```
df['2021']['high'].max()
```

Second code use `idxmin`:

```
df['2020-01-02':'2021-01-03']['low'].idxmin()
```